# VBA Excel Format Range when value is found

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm trying to implement a macro that looks for the words "TRUE" and "FALSE" in a huge array of data - and then, when found, changes the color of the cells above it.

Specifically, I would like it to color not the TRUE/FALSE-cell, but the 30 cells directly above it. This is where things get tricky... I hope someone can help.

I've tried adapting the below code, but mostly I'm adding it as inspiration at this point.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    lRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MR = Range("C2:C" & lRow)
    For Each cell In MR
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Yes"
                cell_colour = 4
            Case "y"
                cell_colour = 4
            Case Else
                cell_colour = 3
            End Select
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = cell_colour
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the 30 a fixed value or can the number of rows vary depending on certain conditions?

Comment: It's always 30!

Comment: does it stop when it finds "TRUE" or "FALSE" or continue looking. If the first is true, why don't you color the whole thing first, then start uncolor the array from "TRUE" / "FALSE"

Comment: It shouldn't stop when finding a case - in the array it will find hundreds of "FALSE" and "TRUE" - and it should color each and everyone one accordingly.

Comment: @CTH, added a fast approach via a datafield array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using a datafield array**

Looping through a range is always time consuming; this should speed it up.

*Caveat:* Formatting single cells can maximize file size, so at least I reformat the whole column C to `xlColorIndexNone`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Mark30CellsAbove()
Dim ws   As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
Dim v    As Variant
Dim i    As Long, j As Long, n As Long, m As Long, r As Long
Dim Rng  As Range
Dim t    As Double
' stop watch
  t = Timer
' get last row in column C
  n = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' get values to one based 2dim array
  v = ws.Range("C1:C" & n).Value
' clear existing colors over the WHOLE column to minimize file size
  ws.Range("C:C").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
' loop through C2:Cn and mark 30 rows before found condition
  For i = 2 To n
      ' check condition, find string "true" or "false"
        If InStr(".true.false.", "." & LCase(v(i, 1)) & ".") > 0 Then

            ' set range block - fixed rows count 30 above found cell
            If i < 32 Then      ' only in case of less than 30 rows
               Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & (i - 1))
            Else
               Set rng = ws.Range("C" & (i - 30) & ":C" & (i - 1))
            End If
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        End If
  Next i
  MsgBox "Time needed: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00") & " seconds."
End Sub
```

Of course you could also loop within `If` - `EndIf`, just to see this slower method:

```
        If InStr(".true.false.", "." & LCase(v(i, 1)) & ".") > 0 Then

            ' Always avoid to loop through a range
            ' For j = i - 1 To i - 30 Step -1
                ' If j < 2 Then Exit For      ' optional escape if one line under title row
                ' ws.Cells(j, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ' Next
         End If
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot. However, I am having problems adapting it to my needs.

If I want to specify that the range is from E5:196 and all rows to the right of this with data - how would you go about it?

Comment: I'm getting a "Subscript out of range error 9" message in the

        If LCase(v(i, 1)) = "TRUE" Then     ' search string "true"

Seems like this is to due with the ranging still.

Comment: @CTH, ad) An Error 9 occurs when an array element isn' t addressed within the the defined array ranges, in my tests, however, everything ran well. - So did you change or misspell above code, did you refert to `v(i, 1)` as a 2-dimensioned array (as it refers to one column only, the 2nd index value is always 1)? At which `i`value do you have issues. You could insert a temporary `Debug.Print "i=" & i, "array items count from " & LBound(v,1) & " To " & UBound(v,1)`  after the `For ...` loop to get the last valid index number or use an Error Handler to check that.

Comment: @CTH, by the way  the `LCase` function converts to lower case, so you would have to check for `If LCase(v(i, 1)) = "true"` or, using upper case `If UCase(v(i, 1)) = "TRUE"` to get any result. I used `InStr` to combine both search strings within one Statement.

Comment: @CTH, ad your first question in comment: if you want to get the sheet's last column number and you have titles in the first row you can use `ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Then you can define a new range, - Sure you find a solution at SO or ask a new question that meets SO rules (cf. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE) at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I appreciate that this might be a very basic question - but while I may have gotten this to work, it only seems to apply to the C column (in your example). 

What I am trying to do is have it search for all instances where the word TRUE or FALSE would appear. In my current setup, the words appear in rows 35, 67, 99, 131, 163 and 195.

They appear in every single column in these lines - until, say column BXR.

I'm sorry to bother you again with this, but can you suggest a way to adapt to something like this?

Comment: Hi again, I will mark this as an answer - and ask a new question to address something I can't get to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @CTH, glad it worked. As to your question: If you want to broaden the search array, just define `v = ws.Range("C1:BRX" & n).Value`, insert a sub-loop `For j=1 to UBound(v, 2)' after `For i=2 to n` and don't refer to `v(i, 1)`  (= only first column), but write `v(i, j)` to your condition in the next code line. See my hint above to get flexible range dimensions.

Comment: Thanks again - this was exactly what I was trying to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

The code that I posted should only highlight cells in column B whose value is different from the corresponding cell in column A. I tested it and it worked OK.

If you want to try conditional formatting:

Select column B, or the part of column B that you want to colour conditionally.

In the following, I will assume that B1 is the active cell within the selection.

On the Home tab of the ribbon, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule...

Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
Enter the formula =B1<>A1

If the active cell is not in row 1, adjust the formula accordingly. For example, if the active cell within the selection is B3, use =B3<>A3

Click Format...

Activate the Fill tab.

Select the desired fill colour.

Click OK until all dialogs have closed.

Change some values in column A and/or B to see the result.

Refer - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2fffa4d8-bbba-473b-9346-5fce8f0728a8/using-vba-to-change-a-cell-colour-based-on-the-information-in-a-different-cell-excel-2010?forum=excel

Comment: This is not that helpful - as my data set is approxiately 30,000 columns x 300 rows. But thanks.

Comment: hey @CTH ,your excel sheet contains true false value in a single column only or it can be anywhere in the sheet ? .. if its in a single column then no matter how many data u have it will work :)

Comment: The TRUE/FALSE values are located in 5-6 different rows.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether the row of the cell is higher than 30 and then it you can offset to change the color:

Thus instead of this line: `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = cell_colour`
write this:

```
If cell.Row > 30 Then cell.Offset(-30, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = cell_colour
```

Comment: It's an array of approx. 300 rows x 3000 columns. The TRUE/FALSE statement will always be in pre-defined rows, and it should always color the 30 cells directly above the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with ***conditional formatting***

Mark all your data and press "Conditional Formatting". Enter 2 rules with *Use a formula...*
First rule is for TRUE. Assuming that you start with Col A:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A31;TRUE)
```

The second rule is similar, just exchange *TRUE* by *FALSE*. Below the formula, press the "Format" button to set the color.

Explanation:
I reverted the logic: Instead of searching for TRUE/FALSE and then format the cells above, I look for every cell if it has at least one entry TRUE resp. FALSE in the next 30 cells. However, I have to admit I don't know how fast Excel can handle such a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

This may be done without VBA. You should set up two conditional formatting with formulas. First:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),1,0,29,1), "TRUE")>0
```

and the same for false. To highlight the cell you just need to use Highlight Cell Rules (the top option for CF).