# VBA Modify Range when value is observed

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get a sub to work that will color fields based on when the values "TRUE" or "FALSE" appears. I've already asked the below question, and have arrived at the code, also below.

[VBA Excel Format Range when value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185265/vba-excel-format-range-when-value-is-found/48186710?noredirect=1#comment83367449_48186710)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MarkCellsAbove()
Dim ws   As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim v    As Variant
Dim i    As Long, j As Long, n As Long, m As Long, r As Long, y As Long
Dim rng  As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim DynamicArea As Range
Dim t    As Double


' get last row in column C
  n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' get last column from A
  y = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' set dynamic area to above values
Set DynamicArea = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(n, y))

' clear existing colors over the WHOLE column to minimize file size
  DynamicArea.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

  For Each rCell In DynamicArea
  Select Case rCell.Text
          Case "TRUE"
            Set rng = rCell.Offset(-2, 0)
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        Case "FALSE"
            Set rng = rCell.Offset(-2, 0)
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5

        End Select
    Next


End Sub
```

This works well - I am able to color the cell 2 rows above where FALSE or TRUE is found. However - I would like to color not just this cell, but all cells in the range specified by Offset. So, if I specify 8 cells above, I would like to color 8 cells.

I hope someone can help - I'm so close to finishing this!

Comment: How do you want the number of cells specified - an input by the user or just added to the code?

Comment: Take a look at `.resize` option for ranges!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Set rng = Range(rCell.Offset(-8, 0), rCell.Offset(-1, 0))
```

Note that you will get a runtime error if rCell is not at least in row 9

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.